# Get all taxonomy terms for attachment, get_terms does not work for me

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

I have created tags and category for my media attachments with a function like this

```
  register_taxonomy(
    'gallery-tags',
    'attachment',
    array(
      'labels' =>  array(
        'name'              => 'Gallery Tags',
        'singular_name'     => 'Gallery Tag',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Gallery Tags',
        'all_items'         => 'All Gallery Tags',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Gallery Tags',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Gallery Tag',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Gallery Tag',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Gallery Tag Name',
        'menu_name'         => 'Gallery Tag',
      ),
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'sort' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true
    )
  );
```

I want to create a dedicated page that shows a list of all of the available tags, when I was doing this originally with the post type I could easily use `get_tags()`

What I was trying to do to get the attachment list was use `get_terms()` like so :

```
$all_tags = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'gallery-tags',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    )
);
```

`$all_tags` returns an empty array.

Comment: Have you actually assigned some of the terms to some attachments, such that `hide_empty` isn't seeing them all hidden?

Comment: Hi @bosco yes I failed to mention that I have populated some of them with the new tags

Comment: @zac, if I read it correctly ([see the additional info on the `update_count_callback` argument for `register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#additional-parameter-information), for attachments, `hide_empty` means "hide terms which do not contain any attachments that have been *attached* to a post" as opposed to "hide terms which do not contain any attachments", so basically if you set `hide_empty` to `false`, then you wouldn't see an empty array if your taxonomy had at least 1 term.

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you!  I thought that having `hide_empty` set as `false` was the default and I had tried it initially without that option at all, only declaring the taxonomy but it did not work.   I tried explicitly declaring it as you suggested and that seemed to do the trick!  If you want to post that as an answer I am happy to accept and upvote.

Comment: Yes @zac, `true` is the default, which means, `get_terms()` will only return non-empty terms unless `hide_empty` is set to `false` - and by default, for taxonomies assigned to the `attachment` post type, terms without an attached media (e.g. an image attached to a published post) are considered empty.